# FFMPEG Errors: "max_analyze_duration" "buffer underflow" "packet too large" What to do?

Tags: ffmpeg, buffer, packet

I have an error while just copying a video with ffmpeg.
I use the command:

```
ffmpeg -i leon.mpg -vcodec copy -acodec copy leon2.mpg
```

The errors:

```
[mpeg @ 00000000020ebd20] max_analyze_duration 5000000 reached at 5004000 microseconds
[mpeg @ 00000000042f4020] buffer underflow i=0 bufi=11286 size=14824
[mpeg @ 00000000042f4020] packet too large, ignoring buffer limits to mux it
```

What do I have to set that the buffer errors don't occur anymore?

Here is a [picture](http://s7.directupload.net/images/130208/v2ebxmhr.jpg) of what ffmpeg gives out first. After that the red errors repeat really many times. There you also can see what the film's codec and so on is.
See this picture:

I use the ffmpeg Version git-5ce023b (2013-01-15) - Win64 - static build from Zeranoe.
I tried some things but nothing happened. I searched a while but found no solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have also had this problem, my workaround was to use a different format, example

```
$ ffmpeg -i leontest.mpg -c copy -v warning leon2.mp4
[mpeg @ 000000000209bd40] max_analyze_duration 5000000 reached at 5004000 micros
econds
[mp4 @ 0000000004718360] pts has no value
    Last message repeated 54 times
```

Now as you can see FFmpeg does put out a warning, but the video appears to play flawless.

Comment: Here is the link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/jrj82hle0sa7q5k/test.rar

Comment: Password: "leon" 
Thanks for your help:)

Answer (score 0):

By using this command you could also use

```
ffmpeg -i leon.mpg -c copy -v quiet leon2.mpg
```

So there are errors but the video also plays flawless. 
I would really like to know what the problem is... Nevertheless thank you for your help;)